# (Apparent) changes in optimization algorithm used by `lavaan`

Tags: r, r-lavaan

**NOTE:**
[ALL FILES TO REPRODUCE THE EXAMPLE CAN BE DOWNLOADED HERE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/44akr2fkaljmazo/lavaan_reprex.zip?dl=1)

I have come back to working on a project after several months. I was working previously with `lavaan` version 0.6-5, but when I came back I tried to update to the latest, which by now is 0.6-11.

The model I'm trying to fit is rather complex, so (although I'm not sure it's necessary to make my point) for the sake of clarity I'm including the path diagram:

[image: Path diagram with 5 latent variables, one named S1 measured by observable variables sp1 to sp8, 2 specific-factor latent variables, measured by variables sp5, sp6 and sp8, and sp3, sp7 and sp8, respectively, another variable named C1 measured by c1 and c2, which also loads on S1, and variable C2 measured by c3, which correlates with C1]

It is worth stating that all observable variables are categorical except c3, which is a (standardized) continuous variable (parameter `C2 =~ c3` is set to 1 for identification). In the following you can see the reprex and its output for version 0.6-5 (please note it's **NOT a truly rendered reprex**, as it gave an error when trying to load the dataset; instead, I pasted and formatted the output manually):

```
library(lavaan)
## This is lavaan 0.6-5
## lavaan is BETA software! Please report any bugs.

load("dataset.Rdata")

lavaan_spec <- "
  S1 =~ sp1 + sp2 + sp4 +
        sp5 + sp6 + sp8 +
        sp3 + sp7
  S2 =~ sp5 + sp6 + sp8
  S3 =~ sp8 + sp3 + sp7

  C1 =~ c1 + c2 + S1

  C2 =~ 1*c3
  C2 ~~ C1
"

lavaan_fit <- dataset |> lavaan(
  model = lavaan_spec,
  std.lv = TRUE,
  missing = "pairwise",
  estimator = "default"
)

lavaan_fit |> summary()
## lavaan 0.6-5 ended normally after 27 iterations
##
## Estimator                                       DWLS
## Optimization method                           NLMINB
## Number of free parameters                         18
##
## Number of observations                          3625
## Number of missing patterns                        28
##
## Model Test User Model:
##   Standard      Robust
## Test Statistic                               142.734     141.159
## Degrees of freedom                                81          81
## P-value (Chi-square)                           0.000       0.000
## Scaling correction factor                                  1.237
## Shift parameter                                           25.800
## for the simple second-order correction
##
## Parameter Estimates:
##
##   Information                                 Expected
## Information saturated (h1) model        Unstructured
## Standard errors                           Robust.sem
##
## Latent Variables:
##                  Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
## S1 =~
##   sp1               0.648    0.021   31.113    0.000
##   sp2               0.609    0.028   22.062    0.000
##   sp4               0.518    0.020   26.108    0.000
##   sp5               0.272    0.024   11.444    0.000
##   sp6               0.320    0.023   13.939    0.000
##   sp8               0.404    0.020   19.733    0.000
##   sp3               0.547    0.024   23.113    0.000
##   sp7               0.093    0.021    4.388    0.000
## S2 =~
##   sp5               0.675    0.021   31.819    0.000
##   sp6               0.866    0.022   39.690    0.000
##   sp8               0.373    0.018   20.360    0.000
## S3 =~
##   sp8               0.496    0.060    8.263    0.000
##   sp3               0.309    0.038    8.105    0.000
##   sp7               0.335    0.044    7.593    0.000
## C1 =~
##   c1                0.612    0.026   23.689    0.000
##   c2                0.753    0.025   29.871    0.000
##   S1                0.648    0.044   14.715    0.000
## C2 =~
##   c3                1.000
##
## Covariances:
##                  Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
## C1 ~~
##   C2                0.158    0.021    7.419    0.000
##
## Intercepts:
##                 Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
## .sp1               0.000
## .sp2               0.000
## .sp4               0.000
## .sp5               0.000
## .sp6               0.000
## .sp8               0.000
## .sp3               0.000
## .sp7               0.000
## .c1                0.000
## .c2                0.000
## .c3                0.000
## .S1                0.000
##  S2                0.000
##  S3                0.000
##  C1                0.000
##  C2                0.000
##
## Thresholds:
##                  Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
##   sp1|t1            0.853
##   sp1|t2            1.588
##   sp1|t3            2.163
##   sp1|t4            2.713
##   sp2|t1            1.228
##   sp2|t2            1.913
##   sp2|t3            2.397
##   sp2|t4            2.889
##   sp4|t1            0.500
##   sp4|t2            1.674
##   sp4|t3            2.260
##   sp4|t4            2.714
##   sp5|t1           -0.509
##   sp5|t2            0.136
##   sp5|t3            1.069
##   sp5|t4            1.997
##   sp6|t1           -0.525
##   sp6|t2            0.143
##   sp6|t3            1.179
##   sp6|t4            2.329
##   sp8|t1           -0.145
##   sp8|t2            0.334
##   sp8|t3            1.123
##   sp8|t4            2.234
##   sp3|t1            0.660
##   sp3|t2            1.080
##   sp3|t3            1.478
##   sp3|t4            2.349
##   sp7|t1            0.005
##   sp7|t2            0.429
##   sp7|t3            0.861
##   sp7|t4            2.102
##   c1|t1            -2.027
##   c1|t2            -0.901
##   c1|t3            -0.384
##   c1|t4             0.727
##   c1|t5             1.209
##   c1|t6             1.734
##   c2|t1            -1.344
##   c2|t2            -0.431
##   c2|t3             0.331
##   c2|t4             1.235
##
## Variances:
##                 Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
## .sp1               0.405
## .sp2               0.474
## .sp4               0.619
## .sp5               0.439
## .sp6               0.105
## .sp8               0.383
## .sp3               0.479
## .sp7               0.875
## .c1                0.625
## .c2                0.432
## .c3                0.000
## .S1                1.000
##  S2                1.000
##  S3                1.000
##  C1                1.000
##  C2                1.000
##
## Scales y*:
##                 Estimate  Std.Err  z-value  P(>|z|)
##  sp1               1.000
##  sp2               1.000
##  sp4               1.000
##  sp5               1.000
##  sp6               1.000
##  sp8               1.000
##  sp3               1.000
##  sp7               1.000
##  c1                1.000
##  c2                1.000
```

Now, the problem is that when I tried it with the updated version of the package, I haven't been able to reproduce the same results, which seems to be due to the parameters related to observable variable `sp7` not properly converging; at least that is what seems to happen when one compares the fit statistics among the different versions. However, lavaan says that the model converges normally. I have tried reproducing the reprex with the different versions from 0.6-5 to 0.6-11, and gather the results for fit indices and the parameters related to `sp7` (this output omits the model summary above, for conciseness):

```
if(!require(renv, warn.conflicts = FALSE)) install.packages("renv")
# Loading required package: renv

renv::activate()
# * Project 'C:/Users/Mori.P16/OneDrive - UAM/Workspace/R_bug_reporting_and_help' loaded. [renv 0.15.4]
renv::install("xfun")
# Installing xfun [0.30] ...
# OK [linked cache]

test_version <- function(version) {

  renv::use(paste0("lavaan@", version))

  source("lavaan_test.R", encoding = 'UTF-8')

  estimates <- lavaan_fit |> parameterestimates()
  select_est <- estimates[
    estimates$lhs %in% c("sp7", "S3") &
      estimates$rhs == "sp7" &
      estimates$op != "~*~",
  ]
  param_est <- select_est$est
  names(param_est) <- paste(select_est$lhs, select_est$rhs,sep = '.')

  list(
    version = version,
    iterations = lavaan_fit |> lavInspect("iterations"),
    converged = lavaan_fit |> lavInspect("converged")
  ) |>
    append(fitmeasures(lavaan_fit, c("chisq", "chisq.scaled"))) |>
    append(param_est) |>
    as.data.frame()
}

lavaan_versions <- paste0("0.6-", 5:11)

result <- data.frame()

for (version in lavaan_versions) {

  result <- result |> rbind(
    xfun::Rscript_call(
      test_version, list(version = version)
    )
  )
}
# * renv is installing 1 package(s) and their dependencies ... Installing MASS [7.3-57] ...
#         OK [linked cache]
# Installing tmvnsim [1.0-2] ...
#         OK [linked cache]
# Installing mnormt [2.0.2] ...
#         OK [linked cache]
# Installing pbivnorm [0.6.0] ...
#         OK [linked cache]
# Installing numDeriv [2016.8-1.1] ...
#         OK [linked cache]
# Installing lavaan [0.6-5] ...
#         OK [linked cache]
# Done!
# This is lavaan 0.6-5
# lavaan is BETA software! Please report any bugs.
# * renv is installing 1 package(s) and their dependencies ... Installing MASS [7.3-57] ...
#         OK [linked cache]
# Installing tmvnsim [1.0-2] ...
#         OK [linked cache]
# Installing mnormt [2.0.2] ...
#         OK [linked cache]
# Installing pbivnorm [0.6.0] ...
#         OK [linked cache]
# Installing numDeriv [2016.8-1.1] ...
#         OK [linked cache]
# Installing lavaan [0.6-6] ...
#         OK [linked cache]
# Done!
# This is lavaan 0.6-6
# lavaan is BETA software! Please report any bugs.
# Warning messages:
# 1: In lav_bvmix_cor_twostep_fit(fit.y1 = UNI[[i]], fit.y2 = UNI[[j]],  :
#  lavaan WARNING: estimation polyserial correlation did not converge for
#                    variables c3 and sp1
# 2: In lav_bvmix_cor_twostep_fit(fit.y1 = UNI[[i]], fit.y2 = UNI[[j]],  :
#  lavaan WARNING: estimation polyserial correlation did not converge for
#                    variables c3 and sp2
# 3: In lav_bvmix_cor_twostep_fit(fit.y1 = UNI[[i]], fit.y2 = UNI[[j]],  :
#  lavaan WARNING: estimation polyserial correlation did not converge for
#                    variables c3 and sp5
# 4: In lav_bvmix_cor_twostep_fit(fit.y1 = UNI[[i]], fit.y2 = UNI[[j]],  :
#  lavaan WARNING: estimation polyserial correlation did not converge for
#                    variables c3 and sp6
# 5: In lav_bvmix_cor_twostep_fit(fit.y1 = UNI[[i]], fit.y2 = UNI[[j]],  :
#  lavaan WARNING: estimation polyserial correlation did not converge for
#                    variables c3 and sp8
# 6: In lav_bvmix_cor_twostep_fit(fit.y1 = UNI[[i]], fit.y2 = UNI[[j]],  :
#  lavaan WARNING: estimation polyserial correlation did not converge for
#                    variables c3 and sp3
# 7: In lav_bvmix_cor_twostep_fit(fit.y1 = UNI[[i]], fit.y2 = UNI[[j]],  :
#  lavaan WARNING: estimation polyserial correlation did not converge for
#                    variables c3 and sp7
# * renv is installing 1 package(s) and their dependencies ... Installing MASS [7.3-57] ...
#         OK [linked cache]
# Installing tmvnsim [1.0-2] ...
#         OK [linked cache]
# Installing mnormt [2.0.2] ...
#         OK [linked cache]
# Installing pbivnorm [0.6.0] ...
#         OK [linked cache]
# Installing numDeriv [2016.8-1.1] ...
#         OK [linked cache]
# Installing lavaan [0.6-7] ...
#         OK [linked cache]
# Done!
# This is lavaan 0.6-7
# lavaan is BETA software! Please report any bugs.
# Warning messages:
# 1: In lav_samplestats_step2(UNI = FIT, wt = wt, ov.names = ov.names,  :
#   lavaan WARNING: correlation between variables c3 and sp4 is (nearly) 1.0
# 2: In lav_object_post_check(object) :
#   lavaan WARNING: some estimated ov variances are negative
# * renv is installing 1 package(s) and their dependencies ... Installing MASS [7.3-57] ...
#         OK [linked cache]
# Installing tmvnsim [1.0-2] ...
#         OK [linked cache]
# Installing mnormt [2.0.2] ...
#         OK [linked cache]
# Installing pbivnorm [0.6.0] ...
#         OK [linked cache]
# Installing numDeriv [2016.8-1.1] ...
#         OK [linked cache]
# Installing lavaan [0.6-8] ...
#         OK [linked cache]
# Done!
# This is lavaan 0.6-8
# lavaan is FREE software! Please report any bugs.
# Warning message:
# In lav_object_post_check(object) :
#   lavaan WARNING: some estimated ov variances are negative
# * renv is installing 1 package(s) and their dependencies ... Installing MASS [7.3-57] ...
#         OK [linked cache]
# Installing tmvnsim [1.0-2] ...
#         OK [linked cache]
# Installing mnormt [2.0.2] ...
#         OK [linked cache]
# Installing pbivnorm [0.6.0] ...
#         OK [linked cache]
# Installing numDeriv [2016.8-1.1] ...
#         OK [linked cache]
# Installing lavaan [0.6-9] ...
#         OK [linked cache]
# Done!
# This is lavaan 0.6-9
# lavaan is FREE software! Please report any bugs.
# Warning message:
# In lav_object_post_check(object) :
#   lavaan WARNING: some estimated ov variances are negative
# * renv is installing 1 package(s) and their dependencies ... Installing MASS [7.3-57] ...
#         OK [linked cache]
# Installing tmvnsim [1.0-2] ...
#         OK [linked cache]
# Installing mnormt [2.0.2] ...
#         OK [linked cache]
# Installing pbivnorm [0.6.0] ...
#         OK [linked cache]
# Installing numDeriv [2016.8-1.1] ...
#         OK [linked cache]
# Installing lavaan [0.6-10] ...
#         OK [linked cache]
# Done!
# This is lavaan 0.6-10
# lavaan is FREE software! Please report any bugs.
# Warning message:
# In lav_object_post_check(object) :
#   lavaan WARNING: some estimated ov variances are negative
# * renv is installing 1 package(s) and their dependencies ... Installing MASS [7.3-57] ...
#         OK [linked cache]
# Installing tmvnsim [1.0-2] ...
#         OK [linked cache]
# Installing mnormt [2.0.2] ...
#         OK [linked cache]
# Installing pbivnorm [0.6.0] ...
#         OK [linked cache]
# Installing numDeriv [2016.8-1.1] ...
#         OK [linked cache]
# Installing lavaan [0.6-11] ...
#         OK [linked cache]
# Done!
# This is lavaan 0.6-11
# lavaan is FREE software! Please report any bugs.
# Warning message:
# In lav_object_post_check(object) :
#   lavaan WARNING: some estimated ov variances are negative

print(result)
#   version iterations converged     chisq chisq.scaled    S3.sp7    sp7.sp7
# 1   0.6-5         27      TRUE  142.7340     141.1588 0.3354028  0.8751476
# 2   0.6-6         29      TRUE  171.9748     165.2959 0.3363805  0.8751196
# 3   0.6-7         42      TRUE 3012.3886    2308.7506 0.3340248  0.8880930
# 4   0.6-8         50      TRUE  632.3934     531.0374 1.5472284 -1.3973129
# 5   0.6-9         50      TRUE  632.3934     531.0374 1.5472284 -1.3973129
# 6  0.6-10         50      TRUE  632.3934     531.0374 1.5472284 -1.3973129
# 7  0.6-11         50      TRUE  632.3934     531.0374 1.5472284 -1.3973129
```

As can be seen in this output:

1. All versions give a `TRUE` convergence value.
2. Only version 0.6-5 seems to truly find the absolute minimum (although it's possible that there was something wrong in this version that has been corrected?)
3. Version 0.6-6 and 0.6-7, although don't find the absolute minimum, give very similar values for the estimates of the parameters in conflict (but 0.6-7 is clearly far from the absolute minimum).
4. Only version 0.6-6 "warns" that the polyserial correlation of `c3` with the `sp` variables has not converged (although the polyserial correlation values don't seem weird, see below).
5. Version 0.6-7 warns of a poliserial correlation close to 1.0 (which doesn't seem to be, see below).
6. From version 0.6-8 on, the result is stable, with a warning about the negative covariances.

**Polyserial correlations of `c3` with the categorical variables:**

```
library(psych, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

load("dataset.Rdata")

dataset_int <- dataset |> select(-c3) |> mutate(across(everything(), as.integer))

polyserial(dataset$c3, dataset_int)
#            [,1]
# c1  0.084102391
# c2  0.129168080
# sp1 0.034248413
# sp2 0.004023480
# sp3 0.080149448
# sp4 0.013310824
# sp5 0.033524284
# sp6 0.040043309
# sp7 0.003518951
# sp8 0.078623151
```

**Things I have tried:**

- Setting `mimic = "Mplus", control = list(init_nelder_mead = TRUE)` as suggested [here](https://groups.google.com/g/lavaan/c/eg54I9GEj10/m/bUktoKXiBwAJ) has not worked.

**Things yet to be tried:**

- Compare the results with the Mplus estimation (if I can find an Mplus license which seems unlikely) or any other SEM software.

**Session info:**

```
sessioninfo::session_info()
# ─ Session info ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
# setting  value
# version  R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22 ucrt)
# os       Windows 10 x64 (build 19044)
# system   x86_64, mingw32
# ui       RStudio
# language (EN)
# collate  Spanish_Spain.utf8
# ctype    Spanish_Spain.utf8
# tz       Europe/Paris
# date     2022-04-27
# rstudio  2022.02.0+443 Prairie Trillium (desktop)
# pandoc   2.9 @ C:\\PROGRA~1\\Pandoc\\pandoc.exe
#
# ─ Packages ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
# !  package      * version  date (UTC) lib source
# P  abind          1.4-5    2016-07-21 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  arm            1.12-2   2021-10-15 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  backports      1.4.1    2021-12-13 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  base64enc      0.1-3    2015-07-28 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#    boot           1.3-28   2021-05-03 [2] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  carData        3.0-5    2022-01-06 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  checkmate      2.1.0    2022-04-21 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  cli            3.3.0    2022-04-25 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#    cluster        2.1.3    2022-03-28 [2] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  coda           0.19-4   2020-09-30 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  colorspace     2.0-3    2022-02-21 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  corpcor        1.6.10   2021-09-16 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  crayon         1.5.1    2022-03-26 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  data.table     1.14.2   2021-09-27 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  digest         0.6.29   2021-12-01 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  dplyr        * 1.0.8    2022-02-08 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  ellipsis       0.3.2    2021-04-29 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  fansi          1.0.3    2022-03-24 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  fastmap        1.1.0    2021-01-25 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  fdrtool        1.2.17   2021-11-13 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#    foreign        0.8-82   2022-01-16 [2] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  Formula        1.2-4    2020-10-16 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  generics       0.1.2    2022-01-31 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  ggplot2        3.3.5    2021-06-25 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  glasso         1.11     2019-10-01 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  glue           1.6.2    2022-02-24 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  gridExtra      2.3      2017-09-09 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  gtable         0.3.0    2019-03-25 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  gtools         3.9.2    2021-06-06 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  Hmisc          4.7-0    2022-04-19 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  htmlTable      2.4.0    2022-01-04 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  htmltools      0.5.2    2021-08-25 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  htmlwidgets    1.5.4    2021-09-08 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  igraph         1.3.1    2022-04-20 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  jpeg           0.1-9    2021-07-24 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  knitr          1.39     2022-04-26 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  kutils         1.70     2020-04-29 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#    lattice        0.20-45  2021-09-22 [2] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  latticeExtra   0.6-29   2019-12-19 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  lavaan       * 0.6-11   2022-03-31 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  lifecycle      1.0.1    2021-09-24 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  lisrelToR      0.1.4    2013-05-08 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  lme4           1.1-29   2022-04-07 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  magrittr       2.0.3    2022-03-30 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#    MASS           7.3-56   2022-03-23 [2] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#    Matrix         1.4-1    2022-03-23 [2] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  mi             1.0      2015-04-16 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  minqa          1.2.4    2014-10-09 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  mnormt         2.0.2    2020-09-01 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  munsell        0.5.0    2018-06-12 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#    nlme           3.1-157  2022-03-25 [2] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  nloptr         2.0.0    2022-01-26 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#    nnet           7.3-17   2022-01-16 [2] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  OpenMx         2.20.6   2022-03-09 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  openxlsx       4.2.5    2021-12-14 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  pbapply        1.5-0    2021-09-16 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  pbivnorm       0.6.0    2015-01-23 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  pillar         1.7.0    2022-02-01 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  pkgconfig      2.0.3    2019-09-22 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  plyr           1.8.7    2022-03-24 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  png            0.1-7    2013-12-03 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  psych        * 2.2.3    2022-03-19 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  purrr          0.3.4    2020-04-17 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  qgraph         1.9.2    2022-03-04 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  R6             2.5.1    2021-08-19 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  RColorBrewer   1.1-3    2022-04-03 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  Rcpp           1.0.8.3  2022-03-17 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# PD RcppParallel   5.1.5    2022-01-05 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#    renv           0.15.4   2022-03-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  reshape2       1.4.4    2020-04-09 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  rlang          1.0.2    2022-03-04 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  rockchalk      1.8.151  2022-02-14 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#    rpart          4.1.16   2022-01-24 [2] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  rstudioapi     0.13     2020-11-12 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  scales         1.2.0    2022-04-13 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  sem            3.1-15   2022-04-10 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  semPlot      * 1.1.5    2022-03-08 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  sessioninfo    1.2.2    2021-12-06 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  stringi        1.7.6    2021-11-29 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  stringr        1.4.0    2019-02-10 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#    survival       3.3-1    2022-03-03 [2] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  tibble         3.1.6    2021-11-07 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  tidyselect     1.1.2    2022-02-21 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  tmvnsim        1.0-2    2016-12-15 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  utf8           1.2.2    2021-07-24 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  vctrs          0.4.1    2022-04-13 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  xfun           0.30     2022-03-02 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  XML            3.99-0.9 2022-02-24 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  xtable         1.8-4    2019-04-21 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
# P  zip            2.2.0    2021-05-31 [?] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
#
# [1] C:/Users/Mori.P16/OneDrive - UAM/Workspace/R_bug_reporting_and_help/renv/library/R-4.2/x86_64-w64-mingw32
# [2] C:/Program Files/R/R-4.2.0/library
#
# P ── Loaded and on-disk path mismatch.
# D ── DLL MD5 mismatch, broken installation.
#
# ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

As can be seen, this is a rather complex problem to "reprex", so I hope I've put everything clear. Any help will be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Your question is unclear. "I haven't been able to reproduce the same results" is not detailed enough to answer the question. Please [edit] your question and clearly indicate the problem you are trying to solve and your expected output. Also, it is unreasonable to expect potential answer authors to download your entire dataset and run multiple models. Instead, reproduce the issue with a smaller dataset. In the process of doing so, you may end up answering your own question.

Comment: This might be a better fit for https://lavaan.ugent.be/support.html or even https://github.com/yrosseel/lavaan/issues -- the package author should (hopefully) welcome a reproducible example showing a change in behavior of this form.

Comment: @IanCampbell I understand your concerns, but I think that if you read through carefully my question you'll see that I don't just say that "I haven't been able to reproduce the same results". Right after that sentence I explain what the differences are between the results with each version of the package, the problem I'm trying to solve (get to an equivalent, convergent solution with all the different versions), and my expected output (the convergent one, from package 0.6-5).

Comment: Also, the fact that it's a rather complex issue makes it difficult to reproduce it with a smaller dataset and/or a simpler model, because it tends to have a different convergence behavior whenever you change a single parameter. I honestly doubt that this can be considered an underresearched question. Nevertheless, I'll take in @KevinUshey's advice and try with the support page or a github issue.